# MongoDB to MySQL Replication Automatically

Tags: mysql, replication, mongodb, tungsten-replicator

i have Mongodb server and mysql server. i want to use mongodb for "write" and mysql for "read".

so i am looking for some tool or some process by which we can tranfer mongodb to mysql server on regular interval.

also i need to know the steps for mapping of mongo collection and mysql tables.

I cant find something similar on google so posted here.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ETL tools like Talend,pentaho,informatica and other tools..my suggestion is that use Talend ETL tool it provides lots of features and its a open source tool.

Comment: it very depend - how stable MongoDB structure
very easy to make ETL from MySQL to Mongo, but opposite not so clean

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/momy read this, may be help (I not test it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Talend Open Studio for this transformation process. Here is an example --
[Talend ETL to migrate data from MongoDB to Postgres](http://copyrightdev.tumblr.com/post/109311096968/using-talend-big-data-to-move-data-from-mongodb-to)

- After that build your Talend ETL Job.
- Deploy the jar file to SpagoBI Server. Again here is the idea of how to --[Talend ETL Job deployment guidelines](https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/2157.page)
- Then Schedule your Job in SpagoBI Server UI admin console on a certain interval basis.

This will be near to real time but not exactly real time. For that you may need to take a look distributed computing cluster like Meso,YARN or Spark etc.